# Why should write like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd

[Other Module Notes](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes) in [requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org). we can write a module like this:

```
define(["require", "./relative/name"], function(require) {
    var mod = require("./relative/name");
});
```

or:

```
define(function(require) {
    var mod = require("./relative/name");
});
```

but why i can't write like this:

```
define(["./relative/name"], function(require) {
    var mod = require("./relative/name");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first parameter is given as an array, it contains a list of modules to load, before the callback is executed. The parameters of the callback functions then hold references to those modules.

So have a look at the first example: Here 2 modules are loaded `require` and `./relative/name`. The callback just takes on the first of them via the parameter `require`. The second is passed on to the arguments, but there is no named argument for it. However, since it is already loaded, you can use `var mod = require("./relative/name");` to get a reference of it inside the callback.<sup>1</sup>

As for the second example the link you listed shows this

> This form will use Function.prototype.toString() to find the require() calls, and add them to the dependency array, along with "require", so the code will work correctly with relative paths.

So actually require.js will parse your function and look for dependencies, which then create an array like in the first example.

Your last (not working) example, however, tries to mix both. But from require.js' point of view it looks like this: You have one dependency `./relative/name`, which gets passed on to the argument named `require`. Inside the function you try to obtain another reference to the same module, this time under the name of `mod`. So for require.js everything seems fine, but just get the reference to one module and not both, as you (mistakenly) expect.

---

<sup>1</sup>A synchronous module loading using `var mod = require("./relative/name");` only works, if the module has been loaded before by some other call (not necessarily by the current module).